# Homoscedasticity and normal distribution on proportion data - beta regression necessary?

Tags: beta-regression, two-way

I have a couple of datasets with proportion data. For some datasets the values are nicely normal-distributed and show homoscedasticity. Is it fine to run a two-way ANOVA or Scheirer-Ray-Hare test? Or would you always prefer a beta-regression for proportion data although assumptions are not violated?

Comment: If the variance of the proportions are not too close to 0 or 1 and the variance is not so large, then the beta distribution looks quite similar to a normal distribution. See the right panel of Figure 1 in https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v034i02/v34i02.pdf However, for larger variances (or lower precision) and proportions closer to the boundary the distribution can become very non-normal (see left panel of Figure 1). In the former situation a linear regression on logit-transformed responses should be very similar to beta regression.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference. Will the logit-transformation be necessary although the data shows normal distribution and homoscedasticity already?

Comment: That's up to you and your data. I would expect it to improve the fit somewhat - whether or not that is enough to be of practical importance depends on your case.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I will test if the fit is improved upon the logit transformation and will also make a comparision to the beta regression.